# Is it possible to setup remote play for PC games

Tags: vnc, remote, gaming, opengl, directx

Specifically, is it possible for a desktop with a decent graphics card (say suitable for Eve Online combat at laptop resolution), to provide remote play to a laptop on wifi or 4G?

I took a run at this about a decade ago but found VNC delivered a black rectangle for any OpenGL.

Have things changed? I've noted the PS3 can serve some games to a vita, but I've not tried it.

Comment: Lag is a worry - but finding fast wifi is a different question.

Comment: Indeed this might be fun just round the house on WIFI.

Comment: BTW the wii-u has almost no range...you can use the game pad in the next room if you are lucky.

Comment: FWIW the laptop involved is a late 2009 15'MBP with integrated graphics that are not suitable for gaming.

Comment: Is there a way to make the question 'community' editable? I don't care for the points.

Comment: Try to connect to desktop computer with cable, because i doubt that you will have nice picture with more than 1-2 fps... Try program like Radmin... I am very interested how will you work this out :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run games over remote desktop?](http://superuser.com/questions/209023/is-it-possible-to-run-games-over-remote-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible using a software based solution, and not only from your PC / Mac but from your tablet / phone.

See my answer here:

https://superuser.com/a/778460/342303